# how to Mail a filled up form to an email address using PHP?

Tags: php, notifications, sendmail

I am trying to send a filled up form to a particular email address. But I have no Idea about it. I know a little PHP coding and as far I have studied online I found that PHP already have a mail() function. but that also have some problems. although most of that I did not understood properly.

here is the things I want to do:

1. I want to send the filled up form to the particular email address.
2. I want to send that filled up form to my mobile phone so that i can reply immediately.
3. I want to send that mail to my inbox only (not spam pr junk).

I am requesting everyone to give me a details information about how I can do so.

thanks in advance..

Comment: http://w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

Comment: what problems were you having? Show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use php mail function with all the parameters
for example 
mail ( $to ,$subject ,  $message,  $headers );
Where $to, $subject, $message are php variables to contains their respective values.
as you are posting data from the form so you can make $message from form.
like
`$message =  $_POST['FORM_FIELD_NAME'];`

and $headers you set according to your requirement. For example

`$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: My Name <myemail@address.com>' . "\r\n";`

Answer (score 0):

Use PHPMailer to send mails in PHP

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/‎

PHPMailer wiki page:

https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/UsefulTutorial

Use can use Gmail, Live or any other SMTP server to send mails
Code:

```
<?php

require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.example.com"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = "from@example.com";
$mail->AddAddress("myfriend@example.net");

$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

it can help you..

```
<?php

require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.example.com"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = "from@example.com";
$mail->AddAddress("id@example.net");

$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```